# Designing a complex java object from json model

Tags: java, json, model, javabeans

I need to design the java object for the following json obj,

```
{"img" = { "medium":"http://www.img.com", "high":"https://www.img.com", "extraHigh":"http://www.img.com"}
```

Above can be written by simple java bean with the 3 fields, but the thing I needed to design is when the three fields are null, I have to return the following json

```
{ "img":"none"}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you will be creating a json object just check if that 3 fields are null and than create json object without these attributes.

Comment: will it return the "none" when there are no values assigned to 3 fields?

Comment: how are you building this json?